# Set filter that does not contain string

Tags: regex

The string should contain:
`200` then `GET` then (`text/html` or `text/plain`)

```
.*(\/200)+.*(GET)+.*(text\/html|text\/plain)
```

This is working, and I want to add one more condition. The string should NOT contain `TEST`.

How should I add that condition?

Comment: Outside the regular expression. Which language?

Comment: What about `text/html GET 200`? Still contains all three requirements but in a different order.

Comment: I don;t know what language it use, but there is an input box, and the label is FILTER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplified your regex a bit to:

```
.*\/200.*GET.*(text\/html|text\/plain)
```

Which I I fairly sure still fulfills your requirements (I think `(term)+.*` is equivalent to `term.*`, please correct me if I'm wrong in my thinking on this).

So you can do what you want using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*TEST).*\/200.*GET.*(text\/html|text\/plain).*$
```